# Rewriting every URL to index.php using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to catch every URL and rewrite it to index.php. I have the following code in my .htaccess right now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

It does rewrite every URL, but I always get a 404 saying the index.php file cannot be found. The path it is looking for the file is correct though. What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Update 1**

When I directly browse to index.php, it does correctly display the file. Very strange.

---

**Update 2**

I turned on logging for mod_rewrite using this in httpd.conf:

```
RewriteLog /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
RewriteLevel 3
```

This is what it logged:

```
strip per-dir prefix: /Users/rits/Sites/test/ -> 
applying pattern '.*' to uri ''
rewrite '' -> 'index.php'
add per-dir prefix: index.php -> /Users/rits/Sites/test/index.php
internal redirect with /Users/rits/Sites/test/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure this is because it is trying to rewrite `index.php` to `index.php` infinitely.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

That should prevent rewriting to itself, and hopefully fix your problem.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I'm not really sure what could be causing the problem, then. I'm used to redirect errors causing HTTP 500 errors, not 404. Erm... What happens if you try this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?file=$1`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourwebpage.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the .htaccess from one of my websites that I set up to redirect everything to the index page and it works for me, if you'd like to try it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mywebpage.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the content of `.htaccess` file I have and works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```